# Bringing a gift on my first visit to a foreign employer's office

Tags: company-culture, employer, turkey

I just had a job offer from a foreign company and I'm going to visit their office next week.

Now it's customary in our culture to bring a gift or roughly translated, 'a  souvenir' when you visit someone's place for the first time.

Should I treat the situation according to my cultural traditions or theirs?

UPDATE: I am from Iran and the employer's office is in Turkey.

Comment: How does their culture see gifts? Is it "something we don't even think about" or "something that we avoid doing because Reasons"?

Comment: You should ask your management. While countries have customs, companies do have policies. No one on this site is privy to your company's policies regarding gift-giving and I am voting to close based on my assessment that you are asking a company-specific question. I'll vote to reopen it if you can say that your company has NO policy regarding this kind of gift-giving, which I doubt - If a company has an overseas office, it's got to have a policy on gift giving.

Comment: @JennyD I still don't know their view about such gifts, but because of the cultural similarities, I don't think they will stricktly 'dislike' it.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Thanks. This comment of yours acts like an answer for me :)

Comment: Most companies have policies about giving gifts to, or receiving gifts from, customers, suppliers, or other "outsiders" (like members of regulatory bodies). I have never heard of a company having a policy about exchanging gifts *among employees*, which the OP essentially is (given that he already has an offer).

Comment: The only person that can truly answer this is someone who has worked extensively in Turkey or is intimately familiar with what is appropriate in Turkey. In the USA, one would absolutely NOT be expected to bring a gift for one's employer upon the first visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your first contact. You should *definitely* conform to *their* standards at this point in time. Some cultures would consider bringing a present at the first visit extremely strange indeed. Don't start off by making a strange impression.

It may be appropriate to bring some food (bagels, cake, ...) for a little breakfast with your colleagues, e.g., on your first Friday in the office. Ask your colleagues what is appropriate - especially since you come from a different culture, people will happily help you navigate local customs.

For your particular question, it might be helpful if you could indicate the office's location in the world.

Later on, by all means follow your own cultural customs (and explain them, so people understand what you are doing). For now, tread softly.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to know: so it's not a bad behavior to actually ask such a question?

Comment: And I updated the question

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with workplace customs in Turkey, so I can't comment on what would be appropriate these. I would suggest following @VietnhiPhuvan's advice and asking management beforehand. (I did take the liberty of tagging your question "Turkey".)

Comment: Thank you. I will return with more information. For now, this is what I needed :)

Comment: "Some cultures would consider bringing a present at the first visit extremely strange indeed."  Really? Any specific examples? I've traveled a lot, and as far as I can tell, bringing edible presents is always appreciated, even if it's not expected.

Comment: @jpatokal: "extremely" may have been an exaggeration. I work in Switzerland. I have never seen anyone bring a gift *on their first day*. (Some food on the first Friday, yes.) The Swiss are rather reserved, and you'd leave a strange impression. (Problem with food on the first day: you don't know ahead of time whether the "inner circle" is 5 or 20 people.)

Answer (score 0):

CHECK WITH YOUR OWN COMPANY FIRST. Any company which does business internationally probably has policies which cover exactly what kinds of gifts you can and can't give, and to who, for each country. Failing to follow custom is a problem; overcompensating into appearing to offer an illegal bribe is much worse, and the line isn't the same everywhere.

Comment: He should check the company policy, but as long as he sticks to a small box of traditional iranian snacks or cake I don't see a "bribe" problem.

Comment: The OP isn't going to a client, he is visiting his new employer.

Comment: "Whatever is reasonable, customary, and too small to possibly be seen as a bribe" usually works.